# EOA to EOA transaction: only data, no ether

Tags: transactions, eoa

It is my understanding that it is possible to create a transaction to send just data from an EOA to another EOA (no ether). In this case the data is completely ignored by the Ethereum network and if I understand correctly, even ignored by all(?) wallet software. If so, does anybody knows if there are any studies of the pros/cons of using this mechanism to establish a communication side channel in which I can distribute a message to anyone with access to the recipient EOA?